# Edición de wikis de las etiquetas

Tags: soporte

He visto que el uso de las etiquetas es útil y, de la misma forma en que son usadas en la versión de SO en inglés, también cuentan con información adicional sobre las mismas (wiki). Sin embargo no encuentro la manera de añadir mi aporte (he intentado con java pero no veo ningún link, botón, que me permita sugerir esta información). ¿En el beta privado no es posible hacer esto o se debe tener una reputación superior a algún valor para poder sugerir una?

Answer (score 5):

Actualmente, puede editar el wiki para [asp.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) pero no para [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java):

[image: asp.net wiki popup]
[image: java wiki popup]

La explicación está en la parte inferior de la página "Información de etiqueta". En https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info:

> **edición pendiente**   historial   historial del extracto

pero en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net/info:

> [image: Proponer información de Etiqueta]

Sólo puede haber una sugerencia de edición pendiente a la vez. Debe esperar hasta que sea aceptada o rechazada.