# ¿Cuál privilegio/reputación debo tener para incluir orientación de uso o crear la wiki de una nueva etiqueta?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, privilegios, wiki-de-etiqueta, extracto-de-etiquetas

Soy nueva en la comunidad, recientemente he recibido el privilegio de 'Creación de etiquetas' y he propuesto la creación de la etiqueta [nlp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp), asociando esta nueva etiqueta a algunas preguntas que he identificado claramente como relacionadas con el procesamiento de lenguaje natural ([atendiendo la info de esta respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/440/c%C3%B3mo-crear-o-solicitar-una-nueva-etiqueta)). Pasado un tiempo recibí la aprobación de la edición y he visto disponible la etiqueta, evidentemente sin información en la [wiki de etiqueta nlp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/nlp/info).

Quisiera dar mi aporte en la orientación de uso y/o en la wiki, pero no sé si necesito un privilegio adicional para hacerlo, ya que en la wiki de la etiqueta no me da ninguna opción para editar.

He revisado algunas publicaciones sobre edición de wiki de etiquetas como [Edición de wikis de las etiquetas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/96/edici%C3%B3n-de-wikis-de-las-etiquetas) y [¿Cómo editar la wiki de una etiqueta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/232/c%C3%B3mo-editar-la-wiki-de-una-etiqueta), pero desde mi usuario no me aparece ninguna de las opciones mencionadas en las respuestas o comentarios, es decir, no tengo disponibles ni la indicación de **edicion pendiente**, el **historial**, o el botón de **Proponer información de Etiqueta**. Aquí una captura de cómo se ve desde mi usuario:

[image: Así se ve desde mi usuario]

También he revisado la lista completa de privilegios vs los que he adquirido y no encuentro ninguno específico a la wiki de etiquetas. Los que tengo habilitados relacionados con wiki son:

1. [crear publicaciones wiki](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)
2. [editar los wikis comunitarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)

Esto me lleva a pensar en dos posibles razones:

1. Es posible que me falte algún privilegio específico, en este caso me gustaría saber cuál es, porque me resulta un poco raro que un usuario tenga privilegio de crear etiquetas nuevas, pero no pueda aportar a su orientación de uso o el contenido en la wiki.
2. ¿Es posible que exista un bug con usuarios nuevos, para editar wiki de etiquetas que aún no tengan ningún registro en el historial?.

Mil gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: @Glorfindel te lo ha explicado perfectamente ya. Por lo que veo las sugerencias que tienes pendientes consisten básicamente en agregar la etiqueta [tag:nlp], que no tiene actualmente orientación de uso. Te recomendaría [añadir la orientación de uso de la etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/4444). Mientras tanto, he aprobado tus sugerencias.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh, después de la aclaración en la respuesta de @Glorfindel y la aceptación en las revisiones, ahora tengo disponibles las opciones de Editar información de etiqueta, Historial e Historial del extracto. He añadido para revisión una orientación de uso.

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', habiendo entendido la aclaración de Glorfindel, mi caso encajaría en el punto 3 de la respuesta que adjuntas, con un ligero matiz y es que en mi caso no me aparecía deshabilitada la opción de editar, sino que directamente no me mostraba las opciones (ni enlaces, ni botones).

Comment: @Eli-js cierto, eso me dio que pensar. No tienes porqué marcar como duplicada, es opcional. La interfaz de usuario debería mejorarse para aclarar este punto, pues entiendo que fue confuso. A todo esto, muchas gracias por añadir esta etiqueta, plantear una descripción wiki y venir a Meta con una pregunta tan bien formulada y documentada.

Comment: Disculpad, había dado a aceptar al **Feedback privado**, sin saber que se cerraría como duplicada. Lo siento. Gracias por vuestra ayuda y por mantener esta comunidad

Comment: @Pikoh ¿podrías usar tus galones de moderador para reabrir la pregunta? Sugerí duplicado pero no le pareció del todo. Así y todo, le dio a aceptar Feedback privado y se la marcó. En esta pregunta (y sus consecuencias) vemos dos cosas de experiencia de usuario que [SE] debería mejorar...

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' listo. Efectivamente, hay mucho que mejorar :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sugerir ediciones para wikis de etiquetas no es un privilegio; [ser usuario es suficiente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/295232).

En su caso, ya tenías [el máximo de **cinco** ediciones sugeridas pendientes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/295232). Algunas de ellas han sido aprobadas mientras tanto; podrías intentarlo de nuevo ahora.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nótese que el enlace a Meta.SE de [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/209901) también está disponible (traducido) en nuestra Meta: [¿Por qué está deshabilitado el botón de editar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1580/83). Eso sí, algo desactualizado.